# A basic question related with the solutions of linear programming problems

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

I have to select one option from the problem statement given below.

Which of the following statements is true in case of linear programming.

$1$: An optimal solution exists at extreme points of a set of feasible solutions.

$2$: An optimal solution gives a hyperplane which is a  supporting hyperplane to the set of feasible solutions.

$3$. Extreme points and basic feasible solutions are in one-one correspondence.

$4$: A set of feasible solutions is not necessarily a convex set.

**My answer:**  Option $1$ is correct as optimal solution exists at extreme points of a set of feasible solutions.

Option $3$ is wrong as set of feasible solutions may be infinite while extreme points are finite.
Option $4$ is wrong as set of feasible solutions are convex set. 
I am not sure about the option $2$ whether. However, answer key says that only option $2$ is correct. 
Could somebody explain me which option would be correct?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I wonder , why $(1)$ is wrong.

Comment: $(2)$ is correct, if the empty set, a point , a line and a plane are all considered to be a hyperplane.

Comment: Does "supporting" mean a part of the hyper plane ?

Comment: @peter Thanks for the answer. Nothing is mentioned about 'supportiing'.

Comment: Option (1) is incorrect since there are linear programming problems with no optimal solution.

Comment: @doug But then, there are no extreme points, or am I wrong ?

Comment: @peter:Maximize x subject to x+y>=1 and x>=0.  The feasible region has one extreme point (0,1), but the linear programming problem has no optimal solution.

Comment: @monalisa I wonder why 3 would be incorrect. Extreme points corresponds to vertices of polytope, and verticies and basic feasible solutions ( in standard from i.e. $max$  $c^{T}x$,  $Ax=b^{T}, x>=0$ ) are equivalent.

Comment: @DougChatham It can also be wrong for LPs which have an optimal solution such as $\min x_2$ s.t. $x_2 \geq 0$. In this case the whole $x_1$-axis are optimal solutions but no extreme points exist.